# boost::program_options - does it do an exact string matching for command line options?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, command-line-arguments, boost-program-options

There seems to be a problem the way boost::program_options's options_description matching is done.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::program_options::options_description desc("CmdLine utility");
    desc.add_options()
        ("hel", "hel message")
        ("help", "produce help message")
        ("helps","helps message")       
    ;
    boost::program_options::variables_map vm;
    boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_command_line(argc, argv,desc), vm);
    boost::program_options::notify(vm);

    if(vm.count("help")) {
        std::cout << desc << std::endl;
    }
    if(vm.count("helps")) {
        std::cout << "helps..." << std::endl;
    }
    if(vm.count("hel")) {
        std::cout << "hel..." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output -

```
C:\code>cmd.exe --helps
helps...
C:\code>cmd.exe --help
helps...
C:\code>cmd.exe --hel
helps...
```

The output changes if I change the order in which options are added using `add_options()` call. Also it looks like program_options does not do a complete command string matching, so even if you enter a substring of the option, it will consider it as a valid option without doing a complete string comparison. If this is a boost::program_options feature, is there any way to force it to do exact string matching rather than doing it with substring matching ? (I am using Boost version 1.42)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, program_option has allow_guessing style bit on, so a substring match is sufficient. The behaviour you observe, where an option is matching a prefix of the command line, even when there's a different option that matches fully, is a bug. It's fixed in 1.45.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you called wrongly. You example is fine. Look at the output I got :

```
[vladimir@asa example]$ ./a.out --help
CmdLine utility:
  --hel                 hel message
  --help                produce help message
  --helps               helps message

[vladimir@asa example]$ ./a.out --hel
hel...
[vladimir@asa example]$ ./a.out --helps
helps...
```

Comment: I tried it on my Linux machine but the output did not match with what you've posted. I am using boost 1.42 and g++ (gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)). Which boost and g++ version are you using ?

Comment: @Onkar I am using fedora 9, g++ 4.3.0 and boost 1.34.1. They are out-dated, but I do not think the functionality of boost::program_options changes in the meantime.